Convert a column into date/time if the column was imported as a character in R
I'm writing a script to automate a process for intaking Excel data. The spreadsheet being processed will always have the same number of columns (58 total) and the same field names. There are 6 columns that contain dates and time in this format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, which shows up in the correct format in Excel. However, I've noticed that during my import into R, some of the columns will import the date/time columns as decimal time and it's not always the same ones. The column type becomes a character column. In the example below, time2 is the column that imported as character but it could be time3 or time4 or both at the next import.
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

time1 <- ymd_hms(c("2024-03-21 10:55:00", "2024-01-22 04:37:02", "2024-5-3 23:43:09" ))
time2 <- as.character(c("44651.422222222223", "44652.873611111114", "44654.685416666667" ))
time3 <- ymd_hms(c("2024-03-01 12:15:19", "2024-1-18 01:07:20", "2024-5-6 13:33:29" ))
time4 <- ymd_hms(c("2024-11-17 08:05:26", "2024-09-12 10:13:11", "2024-4-3 12:53:30" ))
time5 <- ymd_hms(c("2024-09-19 01:45:42", "2024-11-26 06:00:20", "2024-5-13 22:03:05" ))
time6 <- ymd_hms(c("2024-05-29 03:25:37", "2024-08-02 08:05:28", "2024-12-23 03:13:6" ))
col1 <- c("blah", "blah", "blah")
col2 <- c("blah", "blah", "blah")
col3 <- c("blah", "blah", "blah")

df <- data.frame(time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6, col1, col2, col3)

Because I don't know which column is going to import as character, I want write something to ensure that if it does get imported as character, it will be converted to date/time. My plan is isolate out the character date/time columns, convert them, and rejoin to the dataframe afterwards.
times <- c("time1", "time2", "time3", "time4", "time5", "time6")
char_col <- df %>%  select(matches(times)) %>% select(where(is.character))
char_col2 <- ymd_hms(char_col)

This is the error:
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 

I'm a beginner in R so I don't really understand where I went wrong. Any advice on how to fix this?

How are you reading your Excel file? My suggestion is to use readxl::read_excel() with an appropriate col_types vector, ex. col_types = c("date","date",text"). With an unambigous data import, you might avoid the necessity to transform.

You can use dplyr's across function to apply a function to columns that meet conditions, for example df |> mutate(across(starts_with("time") & where(is.character), \(x) as.POSIXct(as.numeric(x), origin = "1900-01-01"))) will only run on columns that are character class and have names that start with time and will attempt to convert them to numeric, then to a date time with the specified origin. (You could switch out my as.posixct conversion for any other function that works to convert your numbers to dates.) But I agree with Vince - the farther upstream you solve this, the better.

^ A tricky thing with across() that I haven't cracked is that it can only output one class across the columns it touches (I think). So I couldn't figure out how to take a range of candidate columns and run a test (like !is.na(parse_number(.x))) and use that to either output a datetime (when TRUE) or the original character data (when FALSE). Is there a good way?

@JonSpring not sure... that would make a good question on its own. Though perhaps a solution would be to put those conditions in the where() rather than in the function.

Using tidyselect::where with a regex in combination with across
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(\(x) all(grepl("^\\d+\\.\\d+$", x))), ~ 
    as.POSIXct(as.Date(as.numeric(.x), origin="1899-12-30"))))

output
                time1               time2               time3
1 2024-03-21 10:55:00 2022-03-31 10:08:00 2024-03-01 12:15:19
2 2024-01-22 04:37:02 2022-04-01 20:58:00 2024-01-18 01:07:20
3 2024-05-03 23:43:09 2022-04-03 16:27:00 2024-05-06 13:33:29
                time4               time5               time6 col1 col2 col3
1 2024-11-17 08:05:26 2024-09-19 01:45:42 2024-05-29 03:25:37 blah blah blah
2 2024-09-12 10:13:11 2024-11-26 06:00:20 2024-08-02 08:05:28 blah blah blah
3 2024-04-03 12:53:30 2024-05-13 22:03:05 2024-12-23 03:13:06 blah blah blah


try_fn <- function(x){
  tryCatch(as.POSIXct(as.Date(as.numeric(x), origin = "1900-01-01")),
         warning = \(y)eval(y$call[[2]][[2]]))
}
df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), try_fn))
                time1               time2               time3               time4               time5               time6 col1 col2 col3
1 2024-03-21 10:55:00 2022-04-02 10:08:00 2024-03-01 12:15:19 2024-11-17 08:05:26 2024-09-19 01:45:42 2024-05-29 03:25:37 blah blah blah
2 2024-01-22 04:37:02 2022-04-03 20:58:00 2024-01-18 01:07:20 2024-09-12 10:13:11 2024-11-26 06:00:20 2024-08-02 08:05:28 blah blah blah
3 2024-05-03 23:43:09 2022-04-05 16:27:00 2024-05-06 13:33:29 2024-04-03 12:53:30 2024-05-13 22:03:05 2024-12-23 03:13:06 blah blah blah

